# fetch record from with dependent relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I have the following tables.

```
users -> id, name, email, password
diplomas -> id, name
user_diploma -> user_id, diploma_id
invoices -> id, user_id, total_amount
invoice_items -> id, item_id, item_type // items can be diplomas or any other models also.
payments -> id, invoice_id, paid_amount
```

1. I want to get all the users which have full paid total amount of the
   diploma invoice.
2. I want also get all the users which have not full paid total amount
   of the diploma invoice.

I'm currently looping through the each relation.

```
$users = User::has('diplomas');
```

then foreach loop on users and get all invoices.

```
$users = User::has('diplomas');
        if($this->paymentStatus == 'full_paid'){
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $diplomas = $user->diplomas->pluck('id')->toArray();
                $invoices = $user->invoices()
                                 ->whereHas('items', function ($q) use ($diplomas) {
                                    $q->whereItemType(\App\Models\Diploma::class);
                                    $q->whereIn('item_id', $diplomas);
                                })
                                ->whereHas('payments', function ($q){
                                    // still don't know how to fetch the invoice id here to compare the total paid amount
                                })->get();
                $allInvoices = $allInvoices->merge($invoices);
            }
        }
        else if($this->paymentStatus == 'less_paid'){

        }
        else if($this->paymentStatus == 'no_paid'){

        }
```

But I'm still unable to find actual records.

Answer (score 0):

your question is different and your code is different.

if you want relation data then you can fetch relation data using **"With"**
and if you want less_paid | no_paid then you can use where statement in your relation model function .